# Retrieve duration in seconds from string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

Use regular expression to retrieve a pattern.

Hi everyone,

I have a string (for example "this is a 30s video"), and i'm trying to retrieve the duration(30s) from the string, which i'll later use in a different part of the program. I'm using the re library in python, but it seems to be not working. Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the code i'm using to get the duration from the string:
def parse_duration(string):
    duration = None

```
matching_pattern = "\(([0-9]+)([msh])\)"
s = re.search(matching_pattern, string)
```

i'd like the code to be able to get 30s from the string, but it can't seem to be able to do it.

Comment: Use `matching_pattern = r"\(([0-9]+[msh])\)"` and then `return s.group(1)`

Comment: Why are you literally trying to match parentheses? What is the point of `\(` and `\)`? Do you expect the duration to always be contained in parentheses like `this is a (30s) video`?

Comment: Just one question: are there any round brackets around 30s in your input?

Answer (score 1):

Just change your pattern to:

```
matching_pattern = r"\b[0-9]+[msh]\b"
```

Here is an example:

```
>>> s = re.search(matching_pattern, "this is a 30s video")
>>> s
<re.Match object; span=(10, 13), match='30s'>
>>> s.group(0)
'30s'
```

Comment: If there are no brackets then the expected pattern should probably be `matching_pattern = r"\b[0-9]+[msh]\b"`

Comment: That's a good point, @WiktorStribiżew. Let's see what OP have to say, his input doesn't indicate this, but you are right, his regular expression shows that he is probably expecting parentheses.

Comment: Hey Wiktor, Rafael. this did the trick. I needed the integers and string for different functions (15 and s and then call them using s.group(0) or s.group(1)), so i had to slightly tweak it like this: matching_pattern = r"([0-9]+)([msh])". But now it works as i want it to. Thanks!